# How to test rollback scenario in spring

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, transactional

I need to test rollback scenario for this service:

```
@Service
public class MyService2 {

    private final Entity2Repo entity2Repo;

    public MyService2(Entity2Repo entity2Repo) {
        this.entity2Repo = entity2Repo;
    }

    public void create(Long entity1Id) {
        Entity2 entity2 = new Entity2();
        entity2.assignToEntity1(entity1Id);
        entity2Repo.save(entity2);
    }
}
```

I've created this Integration test case:

```
@Transactional
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = JpaApplication.class)
public class MyServiceIntTest {

    @Autowired
    private Entity1Repo entity1Repo;

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Test
    public void create() throws Exception {

        MyService2 mock = mock(MyService2.class);
        doThrow(new RuntimeException("bla bla")).when(mock).create(anyLong());


        MyService myService = new MyService(entity1Repo, mock);

        try {
            myService.create("some name");
            fail("should never fails");
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            assertThat(e.getMessage()).isEqualTo("bla bla");        // success
        }

        Entity1 dbEntity1 = (Entity1) entityManager.createQuery("from Entity1 where name = 'some name'").getSingleResult();

        assertThat(dbEntity1).isNull();                             // fail, however it should be null as it is rolled-back
    }
}
```

The question is, why the organization object is still saved in the Database after the rollback happens?

**EDIT**: Complete source code at github: https://github.com/mhewedy-playground/test-transaction-rollback

Comment: can you quickly try for your test to extend AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests? Also do you have PlatformTransactionManager bean in the ApplicationContext that is loaded via @ContextConfiguration semantics as described in the documentation?

Comment: @hovanessyan same, I believe Spring boot add PlatformTransactionManager based on the data source type (which would be in my case `JpaTransactionManager`) (I just print in the start of the test method: `org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager@6e03db1f
`)

Comment: The code above has issue, the MyService instance created in the test is not managed by spring, hence no transaction is created when calling the create method.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was, I was creating the `MyService` object out of spring context and then expecting the transaction manager to start.

I've changed the test code to the following and now it works successfully:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = JpaApplication.class)
public class MyServiceIntTest {
    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    @MockBean
    private MyService2 myService2;

    @Transactional
    @Test(expected = RuntimeException.class)
    public void createWillRollback() throws Exception {

        doThrow(new RuntimeException("bla bla")).when(myService2).create(anyLong());

        myService.create("some name");

        assertThat(count()).isEqualTo(0);
    }

    @Transactional
    @Test
    public void create() throws Exception {

        doNothing().when(myService2).create(anyLong());

        myService.create("some name");

        assertThat(count()).isEqualTo(1);
    }

    private long count() {
        return ((Long) entityManager.createQuery("select count(*) from Entity1").getSingleResult());
    }
}
```

Comment: This line: `assertThat(count()).isEqualTo(0);` is never reached!!

Comment: Muhammad is correct: the `doThrow(...)` method will immediately return.  A better alternative to `@Test(expected...)` is to use `RuntimeException ex = Assertions.assertThrows(RuntimeException.class, () -> myService.create("some name"));`

Comment: @MattBrock if you agree, then can you +1 my answer?